# Switch between forms in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have list of samples,each sample has own form containes multiply formbuilder text field
I want when tap on sample show me its own form and can give values for fields and so on.
I tried use stack and indesedstack
It Didn't work
Also I tried to refresh widget by Getx it didn't work also.

Comment: what have you done so far Please show me your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.